# Add column values while uploading a file to Sharepoint with C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Currently I'm working on a project that requires the upload of files to Sharepoint. So far i can upload files programmatically without problems:

```
  class SPAPI
    {
        internal void SPUploader(Stream fs, string filename)
        {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://....de");

            System.Net.ICredentials creds = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            context.Credentials = creds;
            context.RequestTimeout = 60000000; // Time in milliseconds




            string fnUrl = "/software/ap_ck/Dokumenten Management System/" + filename;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fnUrl, fs, true);

        }

    }
```

Additionally i also have to add specific values (together with the file) to the columns in the Sharepoint document list. As this is the first time for me working with Sharepoint some of the solutions found online are a bit confusing.

One solution contains the following line:

```
List docList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("members");
```

I can only guess that the "Lists" are the storages for the files? How do i get the title of my list where i upload each files to? Sry for that stupid question, but i have never worked with Sharepoint before.

Comment: Instead of trying at random, learn what SharePoint is and does, how it works and how it's supposed to be used. 90% of SharePoint development is actually *administration and configuration*. No, lists aren't the "storage". *Libraries* store *documents*. List items and documents both have properties, but *documents* have a lot of extra functionality. You may not *need* to add anything if you upload Word, Excel, PDF etc. SharePoint libraries extract document properties automatically

Comment: Sry, i wasn't very specific in my opening question. The C# application has additional functionality. I have to basically split the filename string, analyze it and determine what type of document it is, what customer it belongs to and so on. These specific values for each file (which i get from a SQL database) i want to add to the columns. But i guess i have to get into Sharepoint during the easter holidays.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you highlight which version of SP you are working with to get a better answer. Once you have performed the above code you would need to get a handle of the object you have just uploaded.

```
Uri filename = new Uri("Your file Url");
string server = filename.AbsoluteUri.Replace(filename.AbsolutePath, "");
string serverrelative = filename.AbsolutePath;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file= web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverrelative);
ListItem lstItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
clientContext.Load(lstItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Once you have got the list handle, you can update the editor field as below

lstItem[<Field Name Here>] =  <value here>
lstItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have stolen the answer from a blog [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c772ae1e-ae90-4dd7-abd8-c459d9c43940/how-to-set-metadata-info-when-you-use-savebinarydirect-in-client-object-model?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) but this should be a good starting point.

It worth remembering when you are working with doc libs you have the file you upload and an associated ListItem, Your code deals with the upload and the piece of code I have copied deals with the list item.

I've not tested this but I'm pretty sure this is how you would have to do it.

Cheers

Truez

Comment: I have a feeling that you solution is the most straight forward one, but it just doesn't work with my code.

I have that line:

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@"https://......de/software/ap_ck/Dokumenten%20Management%20System/100_001_000_1.txt");

The rest of the code resembles your solution... But the file seems not to be loaded even though this is the path to it.

Comment: Whilst i understand this is not working for you you haven't provided any form of error message you may be receiving which makes it difficult to help out, I've updated the code snippet a little

Answer (score 0):

We can use Event receiver to achieve this.

First create a event receiver as below.

[image]

[image]

We can add column values after the item added(document uploaded) as below.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SharePointFarmSolutionDev.DocumentEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class DocumentEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        private readonly HttpContext _currentContext;
        public DocumentEventReceiver()
        {
            if (_currentContext == null)
            {
                _currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
            }
        }

        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
             base.ItemAdded(properties);
             //init
             Guid listId = properties.ListId;
             int itemId = properties.ListItemId;
             SPSite site = properties.Site;
             SPWeb web = properties.Web;
             SPList list = web.Lists[listId];
             SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(itemId);

             item["title"] = "hello";
             item.Update();
        }



    }


}
```

More information about Event Receiver, we can refer to: [Introduction To SharePoint Event Receivers](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-of-sharepoint-event-receivers/)

Comment: How do i get the Event Reciever item? I don't have the subcategory Office/SharePoint in my Visual C# items list nor do i find it in the Online tab.

Comment: You need to open visual studio installer to install SharePoint development component.